# C#. Как правильно разобрать JSON?

Tags: c#, json

Добрый день!
Пытаюсь разобрать Json ответ от API на классы итд.
Классы сгенерировал на jsonutils.com

Скопировал в проект, прописал:

```
var fb = new WebClient() {Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8}.DownloadString(URI);
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Example>>(fb);
```

Получаю следующее:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[chat.Example]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему? Спасибо заранее!

JSON - ignn.ru/t/messages.json

Comment: Используйте `Deserialize<Dictionary>string,object>>(fb)` - он десериализирует всё. А потом в процессе преобразования в List - поймёте что не так.

Comment: Если вы всё же хотите Лист - то нужно его сериализировать - посмотреть строку что получилась - и привести fb к нужному виду.

Comment: Возможно к Example нужно добавить атрибут `[Serializable]`

Comment: Если имеете доступ к JSON'у, попробуйте добавить в начале и в конце квадратные скобки, сам сталкивался с такой проблемой. Или же добавляйте их к `fb` в коде.

Comment: Добавьте JSON запрос в вопрос.

Comment: В ошибке ясно сказано, что json представляет собой объект, а вы хотите десериализовать его в массив (список). То ли вы сгенерировали что-то не то, то ли просто нужно убрать `List`.